# Why am I not receiving Internet from my Wi-Fi unless I connect to a VPN?

Tags: networking, printing

Our business recently had one of our departments shift locations to a new warehouse. After the network was finished being setup and everything was moved we noticed that unless we connected to our VPNs, even though the Wi-Fi said "Connected, Secured," we would be unable to use any web browsers or connect to a Remote Desktop Connection. This was not the case in any of the other warehouses. Moreover, we have issues with the printers over here, and despite it being setup for all of us only two of the office workers can print out labels that we need. The port and the ip address are all correct, but when someone tries to print it stays stuck in queue and says error when you go to check what the issue was in control panel. When you ping the ip address of the printer in command prompt, you will also get no response, so I believe both of the issues to be related.

For the printers we've tried printer spooling, removing it and manually adding it back through tcp/ip, power cycling, and every other simple troubleshoot. This is what leads me to believe that it is a networking issue.